# Chainlink automations

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I have a `mapping(uint256 => uint256) projectTime` which I use to map every `projectId` to its time trigger. I want to trigger every project when its time is met. Let's say `projectId = 1` will be triggered after 1 day, `projectId = 2` will be triggered after 7 days, based on this `mapping`. Do I have to register every project? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, no.

In the `checkUpkeep` function you would check each `projectId` and test whether it should be triggered or not. This work is performed off-chain by the keeper network. You then pass the `projectIds` that should be triggered to `performUpkeep` by returning them in `performData`.

In `performUpkeep`, you re-test the `projectIds` that you passed in `performData` from `checkUpkeep`, otherwise there's nothing to prevent someone else triggering any `projectId` at any time.

Comment: can i use check upkeep like this or do i have use some for loop for this                      
 function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */
    )
        public
        view
        override
        returns (
            bool upkeepNeeded,
            bytes memory /* performData */
        )
    {
        bool isFunded = _isFunding[projectId];
        bool timePassed = (block.timestamp -
            (projectToTime[projectId][time[projectId]])) > time[projectId];
        upkeepNeeded = (isFunded);
    }

Comment: sorry. i ask bad question get wrong answer :) Please kindly check the link. But not the question i give the second answer on page below. That is i think a solution what i want tot do. Also what you suggest.  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/139132/mappings-return-false-but-function-returns-true