# mappings return false but function returns true

Tags: solidity, hardhat, chainlink

I have a mapping uint256=>bool. I am giving projectId to see is it registered or not. I registered a project. I use chainlink automation for do something. But when i call checkuppkeep function for testing, mapping returns false but function returns true after registration.
Basicly is_funding public view function returns true as it should be but in the contract _isFunding[projectId] mapping return false. What is going on?

`_isFunding[projectId] = true;`

```
  function checkUpkeep(
    bytes memory /* checkData */
)
    public
    view
    override
    returns (
        bool upkeepNeeded,
        bytes memory /* performData */
    )
{
    bool isFunded = _isFunding[projectId];
    bool timePassed = (block.timestamp -
        (projectToTime[projectId][time[projectId]])) > time[projectId];
    upkeepNeeded = (isFunded);
}
function getTimeleft(uint256 _projectID)
    public
    view
    returns (uint256 a, uint256 b)
{
    a = block.timestamp - projectToTime[_projectID][time[_projectID]];
    b = time[_projectID];
}
function is_funding(uint256 _projectID) public view returns (bool) {
        return _isFunding[_projectID];
    }
```

Hardhat test file :

```
it("return false if project hasnt submit", async () => {
      blockNumber = await ethers.provider.getBlockNumber();
      console.log(`Before ${blockNumber}`);
      await moveTime(s_fundingTime + 1);
      await moveBlocks(s_fundingTime + 1);
      blockNumber = await ethers.provider.getBlockNumber();
      console.log(`Before ${blockNumber}`);
      const { upkeepNeeded } = await governor.checkUpkeep([]);
      const { a, b } = await governor.getTimeleft(projectId);
      console.log(await governor.is_funding(projectId));
      console.log(a.toString(), b.toString());
      console.log(upkeepNeeded);
      // assert(!upkeepNeeded);
```

console of test result:

```
Before 226
Moving time...
Moved forward 61 seconds..
Moving blocks...
Before 287
true
121 60
false
```

Comment: Hi Furkan, I tried a similar code as yours and cannot reproduce the issue, and can you edit your question to post complete contract?

Comment: hi Frank, i have updated code as a new answer below. Turns out we cant use checkUpKeep function like this. On my code projectId is a variable on contract. This was the my fault. So it was checking only the last index of projectId. Lets say i add 5 project. checkupkeep only checking 5th project. Not all of them. So i changed code like below.

Comment: Cool, it is always a good practice that `checkUpkeep` works as expected before registering upkeep.

Answer (score 1):

I came up like this. I will return data perfomData as projectId so we can work on that projectId on chain.

```
function checkUpkeep(
    bytes memory /* checkData */
)
    public
    view
    override
    returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData)
{
    for (uint i = 1; i <= projectId; i++) {
        bool isFunded = _isFunding[i];

        console.log("_isFunding= ", _isFunding[i], i);

        bool timePassed = (block.timestamp - (projectToTime[i][time[i]])) >
            time[i];
        upkeepNeeded = (isFunded && timePassed);
        if (upkeepNeeded) {
            performData = abi.encodePacked(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the my perfromUpKeep func.

```
 function performUpkeep(bytes calldata performData) external override {
    (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
    if (!upkeepNeeded) {
        revert FundProject__UpkeepNeeded();
    }
    uint256 ProjectId = uint256(bytes32(performData));
    _isFunding[ProjectId] = false;
    _isApporovedByDao[ProjectId] = false;

    if (projectFunds[ProjectId] > projectFundingGoalAmount[ProjectId]) {
        _ProjectFundingStatus[ProjectId] = ProjectFundingStatus.SUCCESS;
        uint256 fundsToSent = (projectFunds[ProjectId] * daoPercentage) /
            100;
        (bool success, ) = (projectOwnerAddress[ProjectId]).call{
            value: fundsToSent
        }("");
        if (!success) {
            revert FundProject__TransferFailed(projectFunds[ProjectId]);
        }

        emit projectSuccessfullyFunded(ProjectId);
    } else {
        _ProjectFundingStatus[ProjectId] = ProjectFundingStatus.FAILED;
        emit projectFundingFailed(ProjectId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Good,
If one project has one time stamp then why to don't use a struct, instead of mapping of mapping.
Struct ProjectsInfo {unit timestamp; book idfunded}
Mapping (unit=>ProjectsInfo) projectToTime

Also, with this solution, if you want optimization (packing), better to reduce the size of timestamp, like uint248.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your posted code, You call *checkUpkeep* without the parameter *projectId*.

Comment: yes i am. i have a projects. every project have their own time to trıgger. I want to trigger every project when its time. dont want to trigger specify projectId

Comment: yes i was. But i figure it out.my mistake is projectId is a variable in the contract. So when ever i call checkUpKepp or performUpKepp it will run function with last index of that projectId. So just last project will be check.

Comment: in fact, if you expect to have the same result with
is_funding with parameter projectId. And the function checkUpkeep then imad you know it s missing the parameter.       For your need, to ensure that a project is triggered when it's time. I need to get more information about *projectToTime*. Is it a mapping of mapping? Of course to make a check, I ll advice offchain, but if you cannot, I ll advice to change your architecture.

Comment: yes its a mapping of mapping // projectId => projectFundingTime => timestamp of adding